# SwiftUI how to bind DatePicker with a variable of type 'TimeStamp'?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, datepicker, swiftui

I am trying to Bind **`UIDatePicker`** with a variable that is coming straight from Server but the issue is variable has a type of **TimeStamp** and **`UIDatePicker`** requires a type of **Date**.

```
if(self.shouldShowDatePicker)
{
    DatePicker(selection:self.$taskData.fields[index].dateField.valueTime , displayedComponents: .date)
    Text("DatePicker")
}
```

Now I know that this variable `self.$taskData.fields[index].dateField.valueTime` is of **TimeStamp** type, and since you can see that this variable belongs to a very complex array of fields so I cannot alter the structure. Please let me know what is the possible solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in dynamic `Binding`, like the following

```swift
if(self.shouldShowDatePicker)
{
   DatePicker(selection: Binding<Date>(
       get: { Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self.taskData.fields[index].dateField.valueTime) },
       set: { self.taskData.fields[index].dateField.valueTime = $0.timeIntervalSince1970 } ), 
       displayedComponents: [.date]) { Text("DatePicker") }
}
```

Comment: I got this error 'Generic parameter 'SelectionValue' could not be inferred' after adding your piece of code.

Comment: @Najam, I wrote just inline from your snapshot to show the idea of binding, try updated. Compiling errors might be just due to typos.

Comment: @Najam, tested with `self.timestamp` replaced your model - compiled & worked. Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Answer (score 0):

An extension should do the trick

```
extension Double {
    var _boundDate: Date {
        get {
            return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: self )
        }
        set {
            self = newValue.timeIntervalSince1970
        }
    }
    public var boundDate: Date {
        get {
            return _boundDate
        }
        set {
            _boundDate = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Your binding on the DatePicker would look like this

```
self.$taskData.fields[index].dateField.valueTime.boundDate
```

Comment: @Najam What type is valueTime? Is it a Double or TimeInterval? Is TimeStamp a Custom class? If so, you can replace Double on my code with TimeStamp and adjust the _boundDate get set methods to point to the seconds in the TimeStamp class.